# form validation in angular 2

Tags: html, validation, typescript, angular

I am writing a form validation in angular2.
my error is `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`

My HTML file contains a form i.e.

```
<form  id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate
        [ngFormModel] = "contact" (ngSubmit)="submit(contact.value)">
          <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Name *" value=""
          [ngFormControl] = "contact.controls['author']" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"/>
         <div [hidden]="author.valid">Name is required
       </div>
          </div>
```

I am getting error at `div [hidden]="author.valid"`.
The error is `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined"`

My component file contains

```
import {FormBuilder ,ControlGroup,Validators } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-contact',
  templateUrl : 'app/contact.html'
  }
export class ContactComponent {
    contact : ControlGroup;
  constructor(private _OnChange:OnChange,private _formBuilder : FormBuilder){
    this.ngAfterViewInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() : any{
      this.contact = this._formBuilder.group({
        'author' : ['',Validators.required] }); }
submit(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.contact.value));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[hidden]="contact.controls['author'].valid"
```

Comment: Why? Where What's the difference? Any reference?

Comment: You would need to add `#author="ngForm"` to the `<input ...>` to make `[hidden]="author.valid"` work which causes errors like "Expression was changed after it was checked". Alternatively you can create a variable `author = new Control('', [Validators.required]);` and add this to `this._formBuilder.group({'author': this.author})` instead, then your view binding should work as well. I also would suggest you migrate to the new forms module. No point in investing time learning something that is already replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Because author is not a variable. Use

```
<div [hidden]="contact?.controls?.author?.valid">Name is required</div>
```

Actually, even better. you should use the new forms module **@angular/forms**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol